# User behavior for two multiselect row data table in a popup

Tags: user-behavior, data-tables, popup

What is the best way to organize two huge data table within popup with smoother user flow. A page end user use to create and combine items from different job order.

**Expected User flow:**

1. Select one/multiple row in "Table 1".
2. Click "Search" button.
   (System generate result table base on selection and display show below Table 1)
3. Select one/multiple row in result table below.
4. Click "Confirm" button.
   [image]

**Current problem facing:**

- End user doesn't know they need to click search after selecting rows in Table 1.
- End user often ignore step 2 & 3, and keep getting error in result.

**Things to bear in mind:**

1. Table row might be more then 1000.
2. Column are more then the example given. No column should be hidden as those are requirement.
3. Search/ filter is required for Table 1.
4. User can repeat step 1 to 3, as long as confirm button is not clicked.

**Sample that don't work well:**
At start show Only Table 1(Image 1), after user trigger search button. Table 1 will collapse and show result table(Image 2). User still missed step 2 and click Confirm button.
[image]

Comment: Even by explaining the flow it's not clear to me what task is the user performing. Instead of trying to describe the current flow try explaining what the user action is. What is he trying to achieve? You clearly have an anti-pattern in there against any user mental model.

Comment: Why two tables? Why not simply reduce the first table based on the filter/search?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, we got feedback on user, that most of the time they doesn't know which they needed to select on the first table. So they need all those column information to decide what they need.